# Can't type in text box - React

Tags: reactjs

trying to type in the text field box on the web browser but isn't doing 
anything and I have no error notification

this is the code i have following a tutorial and i can't type anything into the text box

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Form extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super() 

        this.state = {
            firstName: "", 
            lastName: ""
        }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <form>
            <input 
                type="text"
                value={this.state.firstName}
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.lastName}
                placeholder="Last Name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            </form>
        )   
    }
}

export default Form
```

expected being able to type but can't

Comment: you dont have name tag on your input

Comment: smh rookie mistake, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `name` tag on your input: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hfhajx

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Form extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super() 

        this.state = {
            firstName: "", 
            lastName: ""
        }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <form>
            <input 
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                value={this.state.firstName}
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
            <input
                type="text"
                name="lastName"
                value={this.state.lastName}
                placeholder="Last Name"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            </form>
        )   
    }
}

export default Form
```